# Variadic template returning a N-tuple based on an unknown number of arguments

Tags: c++, c++17, variadic-templates, variadic-functions

I would like to have a variadic function template that takes pointers of a certain type T, fills those pointers, and for each of them generate an object as a result, the final result being a tuple of all these generated objects.

Given a function from a library (that uses a C api):

```
struct opaque {};

bool fill_pointer(opaque **);
```

And:

```
struct MyType {};

MyType gen_object(opaque *);
```

I would like to have a variadic template function that would look like this (sort of):

```
std::tuple<bool, MyType...> fill_and_gen_objects(opaque **...);
```

(where the `bool` result is `false` if and only one of `fill_pointer` return value is `false`).

This is what I would like to achieve:

```cpp
opaque *oa, *ob, *oc;
auto [failed, ta, tb, tc] = fill_and_gen_objects(oa, ob, oc);
```

Thanks

Comment: soooo just `std::optional`? `a variadic template function` what should be the meaning of that function? I do not understand.

Comment: I don't `std::optional` would be useful here. The tricky part to me is constructing the tuple with elements constructed from the unknown number of parameters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's heavy pseudocode, I'll answer with heavy pseudocode:

```
template<typename ... Ts>
constexpr auto fill_and_gen_objects(Ts* ... os)
{ 
    bool some_status = true; //whatever
    return std::make_tuple(some_status, gen_object(os) ...);
}
```

Ok, actually it even compiles, see [here](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/fae68960779b7a50)

EDIT: downgraded to C++14 ... that's what you've tagged.

---

Same for C++17 using [CTAD](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/class_template_argument_deduction)

```
template<typename ... Ts>
constexpr auto fill_and_gen_objects(Ts* ... os)
{ 
    bool some_status = true; //whatever
    return std::tuple{some_status, gen_object(os) ...};
}
```

---

Same for C++20 using abbreviated function template syntax

```
constexpr auto fill_and_gen_objects(auto* ... os)
{ 
    bool some_status = true; //whatever
    return std::tuple{some_status, gen_object(os) ...};
}
```

---

C++20 with indices by using integer sequence (untested):

```
constexpr auto fill_and_gen_objects(auto* ... os)
{ 
    bool some_status = true; //whatever
    return []<int ... I>(std::index_sequence<I...>, auto tup){ return std::tuple{some_status, gen_object(std::get<I>(tup)) ...};}
    (std::make_index_sequence<sizeof...(os)>{}, std::tuple{os...})
}
```

---

Furthermore, here is the C++27 solution:

```
void do_my_fckng_work() { bool asap = true; }
```

Comment: Aside from the comma after `gen_object(os)`, this is what I was looking for.
Also I removed the C++14 tag as I didn't need it in fact. Aside from that, what would be different in C++17?

Comment: @slai-nick: yes, the comma was nonsense, we don't want the comma operator here :-) ... see the edit. In C++17 I would'nt use "make_tuple" but rather CTAD, and in C++20 you can use auto instead of the template stuff.

Comment: Would you mind sharing the C++17 bit? I am not up to date with 17

Comment: @slai-nick: sure, see the update

Comment: Damn, I forgot that in my problem I also need to keep track of the index of each element... That's why I ended loosing myself into some recursions. C++20 looks clean by the way!

Comment: Ok I will wait for my C++ templates book to arrive and finish the 500 pages before continue working on my solution. Thanks anyway, I learn from it.

Comment: @slai-nick: for indices, you don't need recursion. I edited in another solution, but this time untested.